# Al ingresar los input y llamar los datos obtenidos, solo repite lo mismo que se había dejado como encabezado

Tags: javascript

Trataba de crear una tabla por medio de `js` en donde aparecería (id, nombre, apellido, email, edad, dni, telefono) pero cuando ingreso los `input` y llamo los datos obtenidos solo me repite la misma cosa que dejé como encabezado.

Este es mi index (algunos `id` y `class` no llevan a nada ya que luego le aplicaré `css`)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="centrarFormulario">
          <form id="formulario">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" />
            <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
            <input id="apellido" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" />
            <label for="email">email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingrese su email" />
            <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
            <input id="edad" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad" />
            <label for="id">Id:</label>
            <input
              id="id"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Ingrese su n° de cliente en orden"
            />
            <label for="dni">dni:</label>
            <input id="dni" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su DNI" />
            <label for="telefono">Telefono:</label>
            <input id="telefono" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Telefono" />
            <label for="calle">Dirección:</label>
            <input id="Dirección" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Dirección" />
            <h3>Ingrese los datos del pedido</h3>
            <label for="asistencia">Cantidad de ingresantes:</label>
            <input id="ingresantes" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" />
            <label for="aplicantes">cantidad de ancianos y menores:</label>
            <input id="aplicantes" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" />
            <button id="btnLoad" type="submit">Enviar</button>
            <button type="reset">Restablecer</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

y este mi `js`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnLoad").click(function () {
        console.log($("#nombre").val());
        console.log($("#apellido").val());
        console.log($("#email").val());
        console.log($("#edad").val());
        console.log($("#id").val());
        console.log($("#dni").val());
        console.log($("#telefono").val());
        console.log($("#ingresantes").val());
        console.log($("#aplicantes").val());
    
        const form = $("#formulario");
        const inputName = $("#nombre");
        const inputSurname = $("#apellido");
        const inputEmail = $("#email");
        const inputAge = $("#edad");
        const inputId = $("#id");
        const inputDni = $("#dni");
        const inputPhone = $("#telefono");
        // pronto usare esto para dar resultados sobre la compra de boletos
        // const inputIncoming = $("#ingresantes");
        // const inputApplicants = $("#aplicantes");
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        function User(id, nombre, apellido, email, edad, dni, telefono) {
          this.id = id;
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.apellido = apellido;
          this.email = email;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.id = id;
          this.dni = dni;
          this.telefono = telefono;
        }
    
        let listUser = [];
    
        listUser = getUserFromStorage("users") || [];
    
        function saveToStorage(key, user) {
          listUser.push(user);
          localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(listUser));
        }
    
        function getUserFromStorage(key) {
          if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
          }
        }
    
        function createTable(element, id) {
          const table = `<table id=${id} class="tabla"></table>`;
          $(element).append(table);
        }
        function createDataHeader(data) {
          return data.map((headerData) => `<th> ${headerData} </th>`);
        }
    
        function createTableHeader(data, table) {
          const header = `<tr> ${createDataHeader(data)} </tr>`;
          $(table).append(header);
        }
    
        function populateTableData(
          id,
          nombre,
          apellido,
          email,
          edad,
          dni,
          telefono
        ) {
          return `<td class="celdas"> ${id} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${nombre} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${apellido} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${email} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${edad} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${dni} </td> 
          <td class="celdas"> ${telefono} </td>`;
        }
    
        function createRowUser(user, element) {
          const row = `<tr id="tr-${user.id}"> ${populateTableData(
            user.id,
            user.nombre,
            user.apellido,
            user.email,
            user.edad,
            user.dni,
            user.telefono
          )} </tr>`;
        }
    
        function populateRows(data, element) {
          data.map((user) => {
            createRowUser(user, element);
          });
        }
    
        if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
          createTable("body", "user-table");
          createTableHeader(
            ["id", "nombre", "apellido", "email", "edad", "dni", "telefono"],
            "#user-table"
          );
          populateRows(getUserFromStorage("users"), "#user-table");
        }
    
        form.submit(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
    
          const id = inputId.val();
          const nombre = inputName.val();
          const apellido = inputSurname.val();
          const email = inputEmail.val();
          const edad = inputAge.val();
          const dni = inputDni.val();
          const telefono = inputPhone.val();
    
          const user = new User(nombre, apellido, email, edad, id, dni, telefono);
    
          if (!localStorage.getItem("users")) {
            createTable("body", "user-table");
            createTableHeader([
              "id",
              "nombre",
              "apellido",
              "email",
              "edad",
              "dni",
              "telefono",
            ]);
    
            saveToStorage("users", user);
    
            createRowUser(user, "#user-table");
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Cual es tu idea, que debe pasar con los datos, armar una tabla debajo del formulario con cada registro ingresado?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Evita la palabra urgente en tu publicacion. eso solo espanta a la gente que te puede ayudar...

Comment: *Ayuda es realmente urgente.* -> Las urgencias las cobro a mayores, como el veterinario. Aquí respondemos en nuestro tiempo libre *CUANDO PODEMOS*, el que está cobrando por hacerlo eres tu no nosotros, así que no metas prisa por favor. Todo el mundo tiene problemas y todos son urgentes para quien los tiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto puede ayudarte:

Primero declare una variable que usaremos como flag, antes de hacer el listener del boton.. o sea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let tableIsCreated = false; // Aquí creamos la variable para que no se resetee al presionar el botón
  $("#btnLoad").click(function () {
........
}}
```

---

Luego en la siguiente función, no estabas haciendo el append de lo generado en el contendor (tabla), quedaría así:

```
function createRowUser(user, element) {
  const row = `<tr id="tr-${user.id}"> ${populateTableData(
    user.id,
    user.nombre,
    user.apellido,
    user.email,
    user.edad,
    user.dni,
    user.telefono
  )} </tr>`;
  $(element).append(row);
}
```

---

Finalmente aquí hacemos uso del flag para que no se cree cada vez que presionamos el botón una nueva tabla con su headers, se deja una sola y se cargan nuevos tr nada más.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
  if (!tableIsCreated) {
    createTable("body", "user-table");
    createTableHeader(
      ["id", "nombre", "apellido", "email", "edad", "dni", "telefono"],
      "#user-table"
    );
    tableIsCreated = true;
  }
  populateRows(getUserFromStorage("users"), "#user-table");
}
```

---

Como resultado final, cada vez que se ingresa un registro, se crea una fila en la tabla con los datos, con una única tabla y headers en HTML.

---

Dejo por las dudas el código completo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let tableIsCreated = false;
  $("#btnLoad").click(function () {
    console.log($("#nombre").val());
    console.log($("#apellido").val());
    console.log($("#email").val());
    console.log($("#edad").val());
    console.log($("#id").val());
    console.log($("#dni").val());
    console.log($("#telefono").val());
    console.log($("#ingresantes").val());
    console.log($("#aplicantes").val());

    const form = $("#formulario");
    const inputName = $("#nombre");
    const inputSurname = $("#apellido");
    const inputEmail = $("#email");
    const inputAge = $("#edad");
    const inputId = $("#id");
    const inputDni = $("#dni");
    const inputPhone = $("#telefono");
    // pronto usare esto para dar resultados sobre la compra de boletos
    // const inputIncoming = $("#ingresantes");
    // const inputApplicants = $("#aplicantes");
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    function User(id, nombre, apellido, email, edad, dni, telefono) {
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.email = email;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.id = id;
      this.dni = dni;
      this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    let listUser = [];

    listUser = getUserFromStorage("users") || [];

    function saveToStorage(key, user) {
      listUser.push(user);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(listUser));
    }

    function getUserFromStorage(key) {
      if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      }
    }

    function createTable(element, id) {
      const table = `<table id=${id} class="tabla"></table>`;
      $(element).append(table);
    }
    function createDataHeader(data) {
      return data.map((headerData) => `<th> ${headerData} </th>`);
    }

    function createTableHeader(data, table) {
      const header = `<tr> ${createDataHeader(data)} </tr>`;
      $(table).append(header);
    }

    function populateTableData(
      id,
      nombre,
      apellido,
      email,
      edad,
      dni,
      telefono
    ) {
      return `<td class="celdas"> ${id} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${nombre} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${apellido} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${email} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${edad} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${dni} </td> 
        <td class="celdas"> ${telefono} </td>`;
    }

    function createRowUser(user, element) {
      const row = `<tr id="tr-${user.id}"> ${populateTableData(
        user.id,
        user.nombre,
        user.apellido,
        user.email,
        user.edad,
        user.dni,
        user.telefono
      )} </tr>`;
      $(element).append(row);
    }

    function populateRows(data, element) {
      data.map((user) => {
        createRowUser(user, element);
      });
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
      if (!tableIsCreated) {
        createTable("body", "user-table");
        createTableHeader(
          ["id", "nombre", "apellido", "email", "edad", "dni", "telefono"],
          "#user-table"
        );
        tableIsCreated = true;
      }
      populateRows(getUserFromStorage("users"), "#user-table");
    }

    form.submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const id = inputId.val();
      const nombre = inputName.val();
      const apellido = inputSurname.val();
      const email = inputEmail.val();
      const edad = inputAge.val();
      const dni = inputDni.val();
      const telefono = inputPhone.val();

      const user = new User(nombre, apellido, email, edad, id, dni, telefono);

      if (!localStorage.getItem("users")) {
        createTable("body", "user-table");
        createTableHeader([
          "id",
          "nombre",
          "apellido",
          "email",
          "edad",
          "dni",
          "telefono",
        ]);

        saveToStorage("users", user);

        createRowUser(user, "#user-table");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

---

**Versión 2 completa:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="centrarFormulario">
      <form id="formulario">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" />
        <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
        <input id="apellido" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" />
        <label for="email">email:</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingrese su email" />
        <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
        <input id="edad" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad" />
        <label for="id">Id:</label>
        <input
          id="id"
          type="number"
          placeholder="Ingrese su n° de cliente en orden"
        />
        <label for="dni">dni:</label>
        <input id="dni" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su DNI" />
        <label for="telefono">Telefono:</label>
        <input id="telefono" type="number" placeholder="Ingrese su Telefono" />
        <label for="calle">Dirección:</label>
        <input id="Dirección" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Dirección" />
        <h3>Ingrese los datos del pedido</h3>
        <label for="asistencia">Cantidad de ingresantes:</label>
        <input id="ingresantes" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" />
        <label for="aplicantes">cantidad de ancianos y menores:</label>
        <input id="aplicantes" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" />
        <button id="btnLoad" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        <button type="reset">Restablecer</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnDeleteStorage">Borrar Storage</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead id="tableHead">
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Edad</th>
          <th>DNI</th>
          <th>Teléfono</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (En un archivo app.js en misma carpeta que HTML)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  const tableBody = $("#tableBody");
  const tableHead = $("#tableHead");
  if (getUserFromStorage("users")) {
    drawTable();
  } else {
    tableHead.hide();
  }

  console.log($("#nombre").val());
  console.log($("#apellido").val());
  console.log($("#email").val());
  console.log($("#edad").val());
  console.log($("#id").val());
  console.log($("#dni").val());
  console.log($("#telefono").val());
  console.log($("#ingresantes").val());
  console.log($("#aplicantes").val());

  const form = $("#formulario");
  const inputName = $("#nombre");
  const inputSurname = $("#apellido");
  const inputEmail = $("#email");
  const inputAge = $("#edad");
  const inputId = $("#id");
  const inputDni = $("#dni");
  const inputPhone = $("#telefono");
  const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  const btnDeleteStorage = $("#btnDeleteStorage"); //Capturo boton reset Storage
  // pronto usare esto para dar resultados sobre la compra de boletos
  // const inputIncoming = $("#ingresantes");
  // const inputApplicants = $("#aplicantes");
  //---------------------------------------------------------------
  function User(id, nombre, apellido, email, edad, dni, telefono) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.email = email;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.id = id;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.telefono = telefono;
  }

  let listUser = [];

  if (getUserFromStorage("users")) {
    listUser = getUserFromStorage("users");
  }

  function saveToStorage(key, user) {
    listUser.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(listUser));
  }

  function getUserFromStorage(key) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }
  }

  function drawTable() {
    for (const user of getUserFromStorage("users")) {
      tableHead.show();
      tableBody.append(`<tr>
      <td>${user.id}</td>
      <td>${user.nombre}</td>
      <td>${user.apellido}</td>
      <td>${user.email}</td>
      <td>${user.edad}</td>
      <td>${user.dni}</td>
      <td>${user.telefono}</td>
      </tr>`);
    }
  }

  form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const id = inputId.val();
    const nombre = inputName.val();
    const apellido = inputSurname.val();
    const email = inputEmail.val();
    const edad = inputAge.val();
    const dni = inputDni.val();
    const telefono = inputPhone.val();

    const user = new User(id, nombre, apellido, email, edad, dni, telefono);

    saveToStorage("users", user); //Guardo user en storage
    tableBody.empty(); //Borro el tbody de la tabla
    drawTable(); //Dibujo tabla actualizada

    //Pongo todos los input en blanco tras agregar a la tabla y storage.
    for (const input of allInputs) {
      input.value = "";
    }
  });
  //Al presionar botón se borra Storage y se recarga la página para borrar tabla
  btnDeleteStorage.click(() => {
    localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

---

Agregué también que se muestre u oculte el header de la tabla si hay o no datos en la Storage, también que todos los inputs se pongan en blanco tras agregar a la tabla y localStorage.

Espero sirva para resolver tu problema, estoy a las ordenes, buena jornada!

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por ayudar, intente lo que me dijiste y si bien ya no aparece la cabezera todo el tiempo ahora luego del primer submit solo se repite los datos del primer submit y el resto no aparece. Aunque con lo que me corregiste ya di un gran paso. pd: tambien el id me aparece como undefined.

Comment: En la noche que vuelvo lo veo y te paso feedback

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Creo que hay mucho código para eliminar, por favor explicame un poco mejor que deseas hacer y te armo algo para que puedas comparar y aprovechar.

Comment: Es verdad que algunas cosas se pueden sacar, lo que busco es que aparesca un cuadro con los datos del usuario que van enviando y que se coloquen uno debajo del otro nada mas.

Comment: Agregué "Versión 2 Completa" con su archivo html y su app.js que ya está importado en html (aprovecho para aclarar que al importar un js o css en html no debes usar el ./). Quedó al final de la misma respuesta arriba.  Dime si se aproxima a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Volví a editar la respuesta, al crear allInputs línea 28 creo, no agregué const, por lo que quedaba como variable global, quedó arreglado en la respuesta.

Comment: Al intentar probarlo me aparece esto "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". No se si tenga que ver con la ubicacion de mis archivos tengo el index suelto y el css y el js en carpetas.

Comment: y como estás haciendo el link al css y el script src en el html?
De todos modos cuando está mal la ruta del css o script, no tendrá estilos o no tendrá comportamientos, pero debería abrir el html de todos modos, como estás abriendo el html? no estarás confundiendo con otro archivo?. Porque ese error justamente es que no encontró la url.

Comment: La pagina abre lo que ocurre que cuando intento usar el submit no reacciona y cuando uso la inspección me salta ese error. Yo hasta ahora usaba el ./ para buscar archivos que estaban dentro de carpetas alrededor de mi index por ejemplo: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" /> . Mis carpeta es asi : carpeta principal>(dentro de esta hay 2 carpetas y 1 html) css>main.css, js>main.js, index.html

Comment: El problema entonces es el link al script, al final debes tener algo así como <script src="js/main.js"></script>, justo antes de cerrar el </body> en el HTML, verifica que el nombre de la carpeta js y el archivo main.js estén correctos. Chequea bien los niveles de los archivos, a veces no nos damos cuenta, se crean las carpetas y quedan los archivos en la raiz, junto con el html o dentro de css. Es muy común cuando solo hay un nivel de diferencia a veces se confunde facil.

Comment: Ok ya esta arreglado y la verdad quedo como quise pero si te molesto un poco mas quisiera pedirte como hago un boton para borrar lo que va enlistando por que por ejemplo el primer usuario que puse hace rato tenia el problema de que el id quedo undefined, pero el resto el id aparece bien. Se que puedo borrar lo que hay en el local storage pero veo como necesario ese boton para borrar los usuarios de la lista. Enserio muchisimas gracias por ayudarme he preguntado a profesores y tutores pero ninguno supo darme una respuesta y de donde me base en esto fue de un profesor que se retiro

Comment: Actualicé Versión 2 en la respuesta, agregué un botón "borrar storage" en el html linea 40, y agregué en js la captura del botón linea 29 y el listener del botón con una función(linea 100 a 103) que borra localStorage y recarga la página para que se vaya la tabla. Puede cambiar algún número de línea por el formateador, pero al menos te será facil ubicar los cambios. Actualicé también ruta css y js (verificar por las dudas). Favor si la respuesta solucionó tu problema darla por solución dando click en el visto al costado de la respuesta y si puedes votar con la flechita hacia arriba. Gracias!

Comment: Con esto ya solo tendria que agregarle estilo con css por mi cuenta MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS ENSERIO, estube 1 mes y medio con este problema que no podia mas y ya no tenia mas a nadie para preguntar, enserio pero enserio muchisimas gracias

Comment: Se lo que es estar trancado con algo, es un placer poder ayudar, me alegra que puedas seguir avanzando, gracias por la valoración. Como último dato ./ es lo que se conoce como ruta relativa, si utilizas React las usarás siempre, pero en html en las rutas es suficiente con poner "carpeta/archivo.extensión". Quedo a las ordenes!